# Eclipse doesn't launch (JVM terminated. Exit code=1)

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error

This is my java version(on Debian 8 Jessie):

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

And after successful installation, I get this message and program doesn't launch:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/opt/jdk/jdk1.8/jre/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Duser.dir=/home/m/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse
-jar /home/m/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/m/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/m/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444/eclipse_1617.so
-startup /home/m/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 2a5001b
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /opt/jdk/jdk1.8/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Duser.dir=/home/m/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse
-jar /home/m/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
```

I have searched and tested many methods (for example installing java8-oracle) but it doesn't work at all!

Comment: I did download this "jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz" and it has jre inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not refer to `/opt/jdk/jdk1.8/jre/bin/java` directly. As it's a JDK, you should be using `/opt/jdk/jdk1.8/bin/java`.

Comment: I doubt it is a reason for crash.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is only issue, but UseStringDeduplication is available only from 8u20, while you are using 8u05. Please update java to latest available version - in addition to some new features, there is also a LOT of bugs fixes form early java 8 version, you don't want to be on receiving end of them.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently had a similar problem for a version of Eclipse that has been running fine for years.  I cut the -Xms (initial Java heap size) in half and Eclipse starts up again.  I will wait along with you for a more intelligent solution.